# SFDX Deploy Multiple Manifest Package Files

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, package.xml, deployment-api, manifest

I have multiple package xmls dependent on each other, they cannot be deployed individually, all components in all packages needs to merged & deployed at once, can we achieve this with sfdx commands?

hierarchy of package files,

```
└───manifest
    ├───package1.xml
    └───pacakge2.xml
```

I know we can use deploy command to deploy single package.xml file

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package1.xml
```

but how can we deploy multiple manifest files?

Answer (score 0):

The new SF cli seems to support this.

`sf project deploy start --manifest manifest/package1.xml --manifest manifest/package2.xml`

Ref doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_project_deploy_start_unified